# Create a dynamic URL of all list items

Tags: sharepoint-online

When you open any item in a SharePoint list, a form opens showing the details.

Now I want to make the URL of these form dynamic so that when I click the particular form gets created

same like the title url of a normal list item i want it of a infopath form

Comment: Caps lock much?

Comment: same like the title url of a normal list item
i want it of a infopath form

please help ,me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you use infopath here. You have to start with the different infopath form type. Which is shown here. Then the defualt form will be the infopath.

[image]

Comment: To make this readonly, you can set the permissions to the necessary users. Or even can create new views and hide the edit modes.